# virtualenvironment - installed django inside virtualenv, but able to access it from outside env, but it shouldnt happen

Tags: django, virtualenv

I installed django using

```
                 "sudo pip install django"
```

after entering into the virual environment
. So after i exit virtualenvironment, i shouldnot be able to access django , right ?  but i am still be able to access django from outside the environment . What is the reason ? i am using ubuntu ?  What i know is, whatever we install inside will be localised to that particular virutal environment only and they will be deleted once we delete that particular folder.Ofcouse i didnt delete that folder, but i think it should be accessible outside the environement, but accessing that , what is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virtualenv relies on setting various things in the environment. Using sudo will change the environment, which may be how Django came to be installed separately. It's also possible that you or another user has already installed Django elsewhere on your system.

At any rate, don't use sudo when doing pip install inside a virtualenv, it is unnecessary and may cause unexpected things to happen due to paths.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, so will i face any problems with that installation ? from next time, i will install without sudo , but i already did that , so will i face any problems with that or do i need to uninstall it , i am actually working in a company, so there shouldnt be any mistakes, thats y asking .